# Container instances metrics are missing

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-container-instances

Metrics for our Azure Container instances has stopped showing up in the portal and when querying Azure Monitor using the CLI.

I've tried to redeploying instances, restart the containers, and disabling features such as log analytics.

These are the options to `az` we use to deploy our containers, with redacted values:

```
az container create \
  --resource-group "" \
  --name "" \
  --image  \
  --registry-username "" \
  --registry-password "" \
  --ports \
  --ip-address public \
  --dns-name-label "" \
  --azure-file-volume-account-name "" \
  --azure-file-volume-account-key "" \
  --azure-file-volume-share-name "" \
  --azure-file-volume-mount-path "" \
  --cpu 1 \
  --memory 1 \
  --log-analytics-workspace "" \
  --log-analytics-workspace-key ""
```

According to the documentation metrics should just be there, so I'm curious as to why metrics have seemingly stopped. I'm not sure if there's some newly introduced option that needs to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, it seems there is no problem if you create the Azure container instance with the CLI command and input the correct parameters. So I guess the possible reason is that the container instance is not in the running state so that the metrics are also stoped.

You can take a look at the steps about the [Container instance logging with Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-log-analytics) to see if there are other steps missing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As far as I can tell the container instance is in a running state and the application running in them are working as expected. What I'm unable to see are the metrics that should be available according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-monitor). And running the CLI commands there only outputs timestamps, name of the metrics but no data points.

Comment: @polarking What OS type with your container instance?

Comment: OS type is Linux. Although not explicitly set seems like the default when creating a container instance.

Comment: @polarking Which image do you use? I change some images to have a try. Some get the metric with values when some not. So I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @polarking OK, I have confirmed that there is an issue with the monitor agent and now it's fixed. Please try again.